# Reading the characters from image - remove curve

Tags: ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract, opencv, python

I'm trying to read the characters from this image. But the curve in between is obtruding the process. Can someone help me with this please? How can I extract the letters from such images?

[image]

```
img = cv2.imread('screenshot.png', 0)
ret, thresh_img = cv2.threshold(img, 125, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
cv2.imshow('grey image',thresh_img)
cv2.imwrite("result11.jpg", thresh_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I have tried to convert it to gray scale and remove the wave noise. I am unable to do it. Please help me with. Newbie to OpenCV.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the following sequence:

---

**1-** Adaptive Threshold

**2-** Morphological Transformation

**3-** Bitwise operation

**Step-1:** [Adaptive Threshold](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html)

---

- Get different thresholds for different regions of the same image for better results.
- Result:

  - [image]

Step-2: [Morphological Transformation](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html)

---

- We will apply:

  - erosion followed by dilation (opening)
  - dilation followed by erosion (closing)
  - Result:

    - [image]

**Step-3:** [Bitwise operation](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d0/d86/tutorial_py_image_arithmetics.html)

- Useful for extracting part of the image
- Result:

  - [image]

Now if we read from the image, result will be:

```py
dbdhm
```

Code:

---

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract

img = cv2.imread("UzhPS.png")
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
flt = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gry,
                            100, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,
                            cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 13, 16)
krn = np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8)
opn = cv2.morphologyEx(flt, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, krn)
cls = cv2.morphologyEx(opn, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, krn)
gry = cv2.bitwise_or(gry, cls)
txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(gry)
print(txt[2:])
```